# Using Serial.read() with const char * in Arduino RadioHead

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to send text over the serial monitor using RadioHead ASK. Text input from the serial monitor is not sent to the receiver. I have read up on C++ theory with char arrays and pointers... it's not computing in my head :). How can *msg exist without first declaring char msg? Please see the sample below. It would be great if you could explain the theory with any sample solution. Thank you for your help!

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Debugging only
  if (!driver.init())
    Serial.println("init failed");
  else
    Serial.println("TX");
}

void loop() {
  const char *msg = Serial.read();
  driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
  driver.waitPacketSent();
  delay(200);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more what "not working" means? You may want readString() instead. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadString

Comment: Hi Retired Ninja, on the receive serial monitor readable text doesn't appear.  However when I set the first line to const char *msg = "Test Message"; it works fine.

Comment: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' in initialization is the result of: const char *msg = Serial.readString();

Comment: The error message tells you all you need to know.  It returns a String. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.  strMsg.toCharArray(msg, i);  Can you please comment on the efficiency of the code?  Is there a better way?  Thanks!

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Debugging only
  if (!driver.init())
    Serial.println("init failed");
  else
    Serial.println("TX");
}

void loop() {
if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
String strMsg = "";
int i;

strMsg = Serial.readString();
i = (strMsg.length() + 1);
char msg[i] = {};
Serial.print("Sent: ");
Serial.println(strMsg);
Serial.print("Size: ");
Serial.println(i);
strMsg.toCharArray(msg, i);
driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
driver.waitPacketSent();
delay(200);
 }
}
```